# Separate two sets with open sets

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $A:=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\{(2^n,1/2^n)\}$ and the set $B:=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\{(\frac{2^n}{3},\frac{3}{2^n})\}$, they are both subsets of $xy = 1$. Can I find two open sets $U,V$ such that $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$?

Comment: Do you want $A$ and $B$ to be unions of those sets you've written? As you have them now, they're collections of sets, so it wouldn't make sense for a collection to be a subset of a single set.

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $M=\{(2^n,1/2^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}},N=\{2^n/3,3/2^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. Show that for any $A\in M$, there exists $B\in N$ so that $A\subset B$; similarly, show that for any $B\in N$, there exists $A\in M$ with $B\subset A$.

Comment: Isn't A a single point?